# Como faço um "onload" no NODE.JS? (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

Eu estive tentando fazer um código para **gerar uma imagem no node.js usando Canvas**, mas estou enfrentando o problema que a imagem não é carregada antes de usa-la.
Tentei usar *"onload"* mas isso não funcionou (nunca executava o código)

---

Aqui está a "base" do meu código

```
const Canvas = require('canvas-prebuilt'), Image = Canvas.Image;


var canvas = new Canvas(300, 300);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img1 = new Image();

ctx.drawImage(img1, 100, 90, canvas.height / 6, canvas.height / 6);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar o `node-canvas`.

Aqui está o [código](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#example) de exemplo, veja a [documentação](https://github.com/learnboost/node-canvas).
Com algumas adaptações usando http para criar o servidor http e mostrar a imagem:

```
var http = require('http'), fs = require('fs'), 
Canvas = require('canvas');
var port = 3000;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/image.jpg', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var img = new Canvas.Image; // Create a new Image
        img.src = data;

        // Inicialize uma nova tela com as mesmas dimensões
        // e use um contexto de desenho 2D para isso.
        var canvas = new Canvas(img.width, img.height);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width / 4, img.height / 4);

        //crie os htmls para mostrar a img
        res.write('<html><body>');
        res.write('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />');
        res.write('</body></html>');
        res.end();
    });

}).listen(port, "localhost");
console.log('Acesse localhost ' + port);
```